# Dropwizard resources and optional list arguments

Tags: parameters, resources, option-type, dropwizard

I am developing a test DropWizard web service meant to act as a phonebook (based on [this Packt Publishing book](https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/restful-web-services-dropwizard).

I have a ContactResource class with a standard route for indexing contacts:

```
@Path("/contacts")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class ContactResource {
    private final ContactDao contactDao;

    public ContactResource(DBI jdbi) {
        contactDao = jdbi.onDemand(ContactDao.class);
    }

    @GET
    public Response indexContacts(@QueryParam("ids") Optional<List<Integer>> ids) {
        List<Contact> contacts;

        contacts = contactDao.indexContacts(ids);

        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(contacts).build();
    }
}
```

As shown in the code above, I want the indexing action to **optionally** filter the results by id (when sending a list of ids). I would like to get all contacts when I'm not sending the `ids` parameter.

Unfortunately, the service refuses to start with the following error:

`[[FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.dwbook.phonebook.resources.ContactResource.indexContacts(com.google.common.base.Optional) at index 0.`

If I remove the `Optional<>` bit and refactor the contactDao method, the route works. The whole point, though, is to allow optional filtering.

How can I define an `Optional<List<T>>` parameter in DropWizard?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: based on [condit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/463324/condit)'s answer, I refactored the action this way:

```
@GET
public Response indexContacts(@QueryParam("ids") List<Integer> ids) {
    List<Contact> contacts;

    if(ids.isEmpty()) {
        contacts = contactDao.indexContacts();
    } else {
        contacts = contactDao.filterContactsByIds(ids);
    }

    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(contacts).build();
}
```

This works, but I can see this quickly get out of hand in case I have to implement multiple filters (i.e. optionally filter contacts by firstName, lastName, or nationality).

In general, what's the preferred way to implement an arbitrary number of optional filters in Dropwizard/JDBI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jersey doesn't know how to deal with an `Optional` parameter. It only handles the [default entity types](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html#d0e7698) unless others are registered.

In this case, though, I don't think you even need an `Optional` because you get this for free with `List`. If there is no `ids` query parameter specified Jersey will produce an empty `List` and you can use `ids.isEmpty()` to test if any filtering is required.